# Activity Indicator not appears center on custom UIAlertView when search view controller push ups VC

Tags: ios, swift4, uialertview, uisearchcontroller, uiactivityindicatorview

I want to show the activity indicator on UIAlertViewController which contain the table view, So its working perfectly, **but second case is when search controller appears on the Parent of UIAlertViewController then activity indicator not appears in center on UIAlertViewController.**

Attaching image before attaching searchVC on Parent
[image: output on custom alertview controller , without adding search VC on parent VC]

And when searchVC added on Parent then [image: activity indicator goes up of custom alertVC]

Following is code of activity indicator

```
var actInd: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()

func startActivityIndicator() {
    self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    let loadingView: UIView = UIView()
    loadingView.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 80.0, height: 80.0)
    loadingView.center = self.view.center
    loadingView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 44/255, green: 44/255, blue: 44/255, alpha: 0.7)
    loadingView.clipsToBounds = true
    loadingView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    actInd.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40.0, height: 40.0)
    actInd.style = .whiteLarge
    actInd.center = CGPoint(x: loadingView.frame.size.width / 2, y: loadingView.frame.size.height / 2)
    loadingView.addSubview(actInd)
    self.view.addSubview(loadingView)
    actInd.startAnimating()
}
func stopActivityIndicator() {
    self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    actInd.stopAnimating()
    let view = actInd.superview
    view?.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

above code I have added in extension on `UIViewController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it by setting constraints by following way

```
func startActivityIndicator() {
    self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    let loadingView: UIView = UIView()
    loadingView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    actInd.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(loadingView)
    loadingView.addSubview(actInd)
    loadingView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    loadingView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    loadingView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80.0).isActive = true
    loadingView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80.0).isActive = true
    loadingView.center = self.view.center
    loadingView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 44/255, green: 44/255, blue: 44/255, alpha: 0.7)
    loadingView.clipsToBounds = true
    loadingView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    actInd.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: loadingView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    actInd.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: loadingView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    actInd.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: loadingView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    actInd.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: loadingView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    actInd.style = .whiteLarge
    actInd.center = CGPoint(x: loadingView.frame.size.width / 2, y: loadingView.frame.size.height / 2)
    actInd.startAnimating()
}
```